# Count up minutes from a specified number

Tags: javascript, counter

I would like to achieve timer that does count up minutes from the value in the div. Be aware there will be more divs with counters that is why I would like this to be done this way unless there is better one.

```
    <div class="countup">
    <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">50</div>
    <div id="timer"></div>
</div>
<div class="countup">
    <div id="targetdate" style="display: none">60</div>
    <div id="timer"></div>
</div>
```

Where  50 and 60 is the number from which one I would like to start counting minutes.
Now I do have script below that justo count hrs minutes an second and I was trying to change to get this working as I want. With no luck...

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"><![CDATA[
$(window).load(function(){
$('.countup').each(function () {
    var targetdate = $(this).children("#targetdate").html();
    var seconds_left = new Date(targetdate).getTime();
    var timer = $(this).children('#timer');
    var minutes, seconds;

    seconds_left = seconds_left / 1000;

    var countdownrefesh = setInterval(function () {
        // Add one to seconds
        seconds_left = seconds_left + 1;

        minutes = parseInt(seconds_left / 60);
        seconds = parseInt(seconds_left % 60);

        // format countdown string + set tag value
        t = minutes;
        timer.html(t)

    }, 1000);
});
});//]]> 

</script>
```

Any suggestions? Ideas?

Comment: First things first: You can't use the same ID twice in one page, an ID is unique. If you want to include multiple elements in a group, use a Class.

Answer (score 0):

For those with the same question if you want to have any number from dive to be increased every minute by one please see code below.

```
<div class="count_minutes">0</div>
<div class="count_minutes">10</div>
<div class="count_minutes">11</div>
```

And JS

```
    function randomIntFromInterval(min, max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
}


$(document).ready(function () {
    setInterval(function () {        
        $('.count_minutes').html(function(_, val){
           return +(val.replace(/,/g, '')) + randomIntFromInterval(1, 1, 1);
        });
    }, 60000);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/pgawronski/6eom5d94/